# Adjective for the Weather

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a word which functions as an adjective for weather. So I want to say something like "He had weather concerns as he went on holiday", but with a specific adjective term in place of *weather*.
In other words I'm looking for something which performs a similar function that *maternal* does for *mother*.

Is there such a word in English?

Comment: My recommendation, however, would be to use the noun adjunct "weather" as it sounds the most natural. Noun adjuncts are basically nouns that function as adjectives.

Comment: *meteorological* might serve.

Comment: Thank you. I think using weather as a noun adjunct might be closer to the spirit of my meaning., but meteorological will be useful as a synonym. Cheers